# The Intel RealSense SDK does not work with other RealSense camera

Tags: intel, realsense

I was developing some application using Intel RealSense SDK. Everything was working fine. I was able to run the sample codes through visual studio also.

Now I bought a new RealSense camera. But it is not working. Do this F200 camera have any connection with the installed SDK? Do I have to reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have installed the DCM software (DCM 1.4 HF2 or use Windows Update to get it if running Win10)
Otherwise, include the error message you're getting